# What is the reason for "DNS Server not responding" error message in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet

On Windows 7 laptop w/Service Pack 1. Pocket mobile Vodafone WiFi router w/ prepaid Vodafone SIM. Internet working earlier with this. Now not. Signal bars icon in Win sys tray has yellow "!" mark. Other postpaid SIM from Vodafone worked in Android phone for voice, SMS and browsing at same time router was/is down. Trying Windows troubleshooting option from tray, shows message in question title above. No solutions given. What can I try?

Answer (score 1):

The command `IPConfig /all` will give an ipadress of the device that does DNS. It is likely going to show the ip address of this WiFi router. If it has problems, internet won't work.

Usually you will want to reboot this WiFi router and if that does not clear the connection problems, you will then want to reboot your pc. Sometimes, the internet can be restored but windows simply does not detect it. So even though you may see a triangle with the message: no internet connection, it may actually work, which can be tested by opening your browser and do a google search for example.

Comment: Thanks. Had tried rebooting both router and PC earlier, opening 2 diff sites in browser too. Did not work. Late here. Will try ipconfig cmd tomorrow and reply.

Comment: You might also try IPCONFIG /RELEASE then IPCONFIG /RENEW. Every now and then I have to do this myself.

Comment: If rebooting the router fixes it and you have to do this often, that's usually a sign of the router failing...as odd as it sounds to say that about an electronic device.

Comment: @BillOertell Thank you. I did try what you said. In this case it did not work (but I know your answer may work in some cases). Also see my final answer below, about how it got solved.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: Yes, good point, Have seen that sort of thing before. - the electronics failing. Sometimes multiple consecutive reboots (at least for computers) works, though.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all who replied. Problem turned out to have other cause. Prepaid SIM 28 day recharge validity period was over. Found issue by trying same SIM in USB dongle, did not work there either. Recharging prepaid balance made both the router and dongle work. Windows error mentioned  seems somewhat misleading though.